# adding parcelable to an interface class for custom objects

Tags: android, object, android-intent, android-activity, parcelable

I have a custom object class but that is implemented through an inteface, how can i incorporate parceable in it.
I have followed and searched about parceable, but it is only for object class.
eg : [How can I make my custom objects Parcelable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7181526/how-can-i-make-my-custom-objects-be-parcelable)

I want to pass my object list to another activity in android.

code :

```
public interface Projection {

  interface Job {
        @XBRead("./task")
        List<Task> getTasks();

        @XBRead("./id")
        String getid();

        @XBRead("./job_title")
        String getjob_title();

        @XBRead("./job_description")
        String getjob_description();

        @XBRead("./job_room")
        String getjob_room();

        @XBRead("./status")
        String getstatus();
    }

    interface Task {

        @XBRead("./task_id")
        String gettask_id();

        @XBRead("./task_title")
        String gettask_title();

        @XBRead("./task_description")
        String gettask_description();

        @XBRead("./task_status")
        String gettask_status();


    }

    @XBRead("/root/job")
    List<Job> getJobs();
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your custom interfaces need to `extend Parcelable`.

Classes that implement your custom interface need to also implement the `Parcelable` interface, including the `CREATOR`.

You can then add an object implementing your custom interface to an `Intent` like this:

```
intent.putExtra("thing", thing);
```

or add an `ArrayList` containing these objects like this:

```
ArrayList<Thing> things;
intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("things", things);
```

---

On the receiving end, the `Activity` can extract the objects from the `Intent` like this:

```
Thing thing = intent.getParcelableExtra("thing");
```

or

```
ArrayList<Thing> things = intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra("things");
```

Answer (score 0):

Full code looks like

MyInterface

```
public interface MyInterface extends Parcelable {

}
```

MyImplementation1

```
public class MyImplementation1 implements MyInterface, Parcelable {
    public final int var1;

    public MyImplementation1() {
        this.var1 = 1;
    }

    protected MyImplementation1(Parcel in) {
        var1 = in.readInt();
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeInt(var1);
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    public static final Creator<MyImplementation1> CREATOR = new Creator<MyImplementation1>() {
        @Override
        public MyImplementation1 createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new MyImplementation1(in);
        }

        @Override
        public MyImplementation1[] newArray(int size) {
            return new MyImplementation1[size];
        }
    };
}
```

MyImplementation2

```
public class MyImplementation2 implements MyInterface, Parcelable {
    public final int var2;

    public MyImplementation2(int var2) {
        this.var2 = var2;
    }

    protected MyImplementation2(Parcel in) {
        var2 = in.readInt();
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeInt(var2);
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    public static final Creator<MyImplementation2> CREATOR = new Creator<MyImplementation2>() {
        @Override
        public MyImplementation2 createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new MyImplementation2(in);
        }

        @Override
        public MyImplementation2[] newArray(int size) {
            return new MyImplementation2[size];
        }
    };
}
```

MyClass

```
public class MyClass implements Parcelable {

    private final MyInterface var1;
    private final List<MyInterface> var2;


    public MyClass(MyInterface var1, List<MyInterface> var2) {
        this.var1 = var1;
        this.var2 = var2;
    }

    protected MyClass(Parcel in) {
        var1 = in.readParcelable(MyInterface.class.getClassLoader());
        var2 = in.readArrayList(MyInterface.class.getClassLoader());
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeParcelable(var1, flags);
        dest.writeTypedList(var2);
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    public static final Creator<MyClass> CREATOR = new Creator<MyClass>() {
        @Override
        public MyClass createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new MyClass(in);
        }

        @Override
        public MyClass[] newArray(int size) {
            return new MyClass[size];
        }
    };
}
```

Using it

MainActivity1

```
public class MainActivity1 extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_1);

        List<MyInterface> list = new ArrayList<>(2);
        list.add(new MyImplementation2(21));
        list.add(new MyImplementation2(22));

        MyClass myClass = new MyClass(new MyImplementation1(), list);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity2.class);
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putParcelable("key", myClass);
        intent.putExtras(b);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

MainActivity2

```
public class MainActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_2);

        Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
        MyClass myClass = b.getParcelable("key");

    }
}
```